# Database query rollback to a savepoint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
<body>
<%String ide=request.getParameter("q");
int num=0;
if(ide!=null)
 num=Integer.parseInt(ide);
String vegg=request.getParameter("vegetables");
int newe=0; 
Connection cnt1=null;
try{
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emandi";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
 cnt1 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
 cnt1.setAutoCommit(false);
 cnt1.commit();
Statement stmt1 = cnt1.createStatement();
Savepoint mySavepoint = cnt1.setSavepoint("sp1");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt1.executeQuery("select Quantity from data where vegetables='"+vegg+"' ");

if(resultSet.next())
{
    newe=resultSet.getInt(1);
}

int newvalue=newe-num;
//PreparedStatement statem1=cnt1.prepareStatement("update data set Quantity="+newvalue+" where vegetabels='"+vegg+"' ");
//statem1.execute();
stmt1.executeUpdate("update data set Quantity="+newvalue+" where vegetables='"+vegg+"' ");
out.println(newvalue);
}
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
    }%>
<script>
 function disp_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("confirm booking?")
if (r==true)
{
    <%cnt1.commit();%>
 alert("booked")
  }
  else()
 {
<%cnt1.rollback(sp1);%>
  alert("You pressed Cancel!")
 }
 }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="disp_confirm()" value="book">

</body>
</html>
```

I've written a JSP page to confirm booking of vegetables. All the functions are correctly working. Except the rollback to a savepoint if a user clicks cancel button.
Even if the user clicks the cancel button, rollback option is not working. Any advice?

Comment: Using MySQL is bad enough, but waiting on the UI with an outstanding transaction? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not advised at all. And you can't call a Java Code from a Javascript event like the way you are doing.

1. You are intermixing UI Code and Logic Code inside of JSP. Try using MVC pattern and separate UI and Business Logic.
2. Ask for confirmation from Javascript before Saving in database. Not save and ask for confirmation and then rollback.